# How to use service that inited by ApplicationListener ConfigurableApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I use springMvc and mybatis.Copy a BaseService and BaseServiceImpl from a project.

```
public interface BaseService<Record, Example> {
    //init mybatis mapper
    void initMapper();
}
```

BaseServiceImpl

```
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl<Mapper, Record, Example> implements BaseService<Record, Example> {

public Mapper mapper;
@Override
public void initMapper() {
    this.mapper = SpringContextUtil.getBean(getMapperClass());
}


public Class<Mapper> getMapperClass() {
    return (Class<Mapper>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

EntityServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional
@BaseService
public class EntityServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<EntityMapper, Entity, EntityExample> implements EntityService {
}
```

I init BaseService use this code.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationContextListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        // root application context
        if(null == contextRefreshedEvent.getApplicationContext().getParent()) {
            LOGGER.debug(">>>>> spring init finished <<<<<");
            //  call BaseService initMapper method
            ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext)contextRefreshedEvent.getApplicationContext();
            Map<String, Object> baseServices = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(BaseService.class);
            for(Object service : baseServices.values()) {
                try {
                    Method initMapper = service.getClass().getMethod("initMapper");
                    initMapper.invoke(service);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("init BaseService initMapper failed", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

          }
    }

}
```

when project start,entityServiceImpl.initMapper method have been called

```
@Override
    public void initMapper() {
        this.mapper = SpringContextUtil.getBean(getMapperClass());
    }
```

but when i use the entityService in conroller.Can't use the entityService which have been init by the ApplicationListener.
This is how i try to use the entityService

```
@Conroller 
public class LoginController {
@Resource
EntityService EntityService1;
@Autowired
EntityService EntityService2;

EntityService EntityService3 = (EntityService)SpringContextUtil.getBean(EntityService.class);
}
```

Use Idea debug,i can find a EntityService with a not null mapper.
But in controller all of three EntityService  mapper is null.
how could i use the EntityService  with mapper inited by ApplicationListener ?

Comment: I'm wondering why don't you autowire the mapper? That is why do you call `getBean` manually?

Comment: [zheng](https://github.com/shuzheng/zheng) i copy baseService from this project.in this project.the mapper in BaseServiceImpl .not in EntityServiceImpl,so use reflect to instant EntityMapper in BaseServiceImpl by InitMapper()

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses chain of beanPostProcessors and it can modify your initial class by CGLIB or dynamic proxy. So this.mapper = SpringContextUtil.getBean(getMapperClass()); might not works as you expect